# How to execute Python functions using Hypothesis' composite strategy?

Tags: python, pytest, python-hypothesis, property-based-testing

I am trying to execute a function decorated with [Hypothesis](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis)' `@strategy.composite` decorator.

I know I can test functions using the `@given` decorator, such as -

```
from hypothesis import given
from hypothesis import strategies as st

@given(st.integers(min_value=1))
def test_bar(x):
    assert x > 0
```

with [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/) using - `pytest <filename.py>`.

But in the case of a function with the `@strategy.composite` decorator like -

```
from hypothesis import strategies as st
from hypothesis import given
import pytest

@st.composite
def test_foo(draw):
    arg1 = draw(st.integers(min_value=1))
    arg2 = draw(st.lists(st.integers(), min_size=arg1, max_size=arg1))
    print(arg1, " ", arg2)
    assert(len(arg2) == arg1)
```

I am unable to execute the tests in a similar way.
When using pytest I am unable to execute the tests (using `python` to execute the python file does nothing) -

```
[reik@reik-msi tests]$ pytest testhypo.py
==================================== test session starts ====================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.3, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/reik/tests
plugins: hypothesis-5.16.0, lazy-fixture-0.6.3
collected 1 item                                                                            

testhypo.py F                                                                         [100%]

========================================= FAILURES ==========================================
_________________________________________ test_foo __________________________________________

item = <Function test_foo>

    @pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
    def pytest_runtest_call(item):
        if not hasattr(item, "obj"):
            yield
        elif not is_hypothesis_test(item.obj):
            # If @given was not applied, check whether other hypothesis
            # decorators were applied, and raise an error if they were.
            if getattr(item.obj, "is_hypothesis_strategy_function", False):
>               raise InvalidArgument(
                    "%s is a function that returns a Hypothesis strategy, but pytest "
                    "has collected it as a test function.  This is useless as the "
                    "function body will never be executed.  To define a test "
                    "function, use @given instead of @composite." % (item.nodeid,)
                )
E               hypothesis.errors.InvalidArgument: testhypo.py::test_foo is a function that returns a Hypothesis strategy, but pytest has collected it as a test function.  This is useless as the function body will never be executed.  To define a test function, use @given instead of @composite.

/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hypothesis/extra/pytestplugin.py:132: InvalidArgument
================================== short test summary info ==================================
FAILED testhypo.py::test_foo - hypothesis.errors.InvalidArgument: testhypo.py::test_foo is...
===================================== 1 failed in 0.06s =====================================
```

I tried adding the function call `test_foo()` but I got the same error.

Then I tried adding `@given` above the function and got a different error -

```
========================================== ERRORS ===========================================
________________________________ ERROR at setup of test_foo _________________________________
file /usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hypothesis/core.py, line 903
      def run_test_as_given(test):
E       fixture 'test' not found
>       available fixtures: cache, capfd, capfdbinary, caplog, capsys, capsysbinary, doctest_namespace, monkeypatch, pytestconfig, record_property, record_testsuite_property, record_xml_attribute, recwarn, tmp_path, tmp_path_factory, tmpdir, tmpdir_factory
>       use 'pytest --fixtures [testpath]' for help on them.

/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hypothesis/core.py:903
================================== short test summary info ==================================
ERROR testhypo.py::test_foo
```

if I do `@given()` - note the extra braces, instead, I get another error -

```
========================================= FAILURES ==========================================
_________________________________________ test_foo __________________________________________

arguments = (), kwargs = {}

    def wrapped_test(*arguments, **kwargs):
>       raise InvalidArgument(message)
E       hypothesis.errors.InvalidArgument: given must be called with at least one argument

/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/hypothesis/core.py:234: InvalidArgument
================================== short test summary info ==================================
FAILED testhypo.py::test_foo - hypothesis.errors.InvalidArgument: given must be called wit...
```

I tried wrapping the code inside another function -

```
from hypothesis import strategies as st
from hypothesis import given
import pytest

def demo():
    @st.composite
    def test_foo(draw):
        arg1 = draw(st.integers(min_value=1))
        arg2 = draw(st.lists(st.integers(), min_size=arg1, max_size=arg1))
        print(arg1, " ", arg2)
        assert(len(arg2) == arg1)
```

but that did not work either -

```
[reik@reik-msi tests]$ python testhypo.py
[reik@reik-msi tests]$ pytest testhypo.py
==================================== test session starts ====================================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.3, pytest-5.4.3, py-1.8.1, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /home/reik/tests
plugins: hypothesis-5.16.0, lazy-fixture-0.6.3
collected 0 items                                                                           

=================================== no tests ran in 0.00s ===================================
```

(I also tried putting the `demo` function call at the end of the file, but that did not change the testing behaviour in any way)

The [Hypothesis quick start guide](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#running-tests) says that calling the function would work, but it clearly does not. (To be fair, the documentation does not specify how to run tests with `@composite`)

How do I test the functions that are decorated with `@strategy.composite`? I do not *have* to use pytest - I would prefer not having to use it actually, but it seemed the easiest way to test the functions (which were decorated with `@given`) so I decided to go that route.

Answer (score 2):

`@st.composite` is a helper function for defining custom strategies, not tests.

What you're trying to do can be accomplished by using `@given` and `st.data()`:

```py
@given(st.data())
def test_foo(data):
    x = data.draw(st.integers())
    ...
```

https://hillelwayne.com/post/property-testing-complex-inputs/ gives a good overview of how these techniques are used.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Here is a minimal and complete working example of using `@composite`.

```py
@dataclass
class Container():
    id: int
    value: str

@st.composite
def generate_containers(draw):
    _id = draw(st.integers())
    _value = draw(st.characters())
    return Container(id=_id, value=_value)

@given(generate_containers())
def test_container(container):
    assert isinstance(container, Container)
    assert isinstance(container.id, int)
    assert isinstance(container.value, str)
```